# How to scroll content over a fixed header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple background image with `background-attachment:fixed;`. On the `.jumbotron` section I have content like heading, subheading, and a button. How can I make it so that when I scroll, the `.jumbotron` content stays in place so that content below `.jumbotron` like it is moving over it.

I have seen this types of effect before, but it isn't very common so it is hard for me to find an example, I hope you understood my description.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/1920/1080);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 10px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
  <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
  <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
</section>
```

Comment: So you want the heading and subheading to stay in place on scroll Correct?

Comment: I want everything in jumbotron section to stay in place on scroll.

Comment: What you're looking for and describing is not parallax, so I've updated your question for you. Parallax is the differential between *two moving objects* in order to determine one's distance from those two (or more) objects. Here you have only one moving object. If you wanted your background to move slower than your content, *that* would be parallax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to do this via `position:fixed;` and some clever use of the `z-index`.

Here's a fiddle of what you were trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/n4ebgmo7/1/

And here is the fixed CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/1920/1080);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 10px;
  color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

What you are essentially doing here is fixing the `.jumbotron` to the top of the page, and telling the element below it, that it must:

1. Be higher than the `.jumbotron` (this is done with the `z-index`)
2. have a `margin-top` equal to the height of the `.jumbotron` so that it does not start on top of the `.jumbotron`

***Edit***

If the height of the `.jumbotron` is dynamic (as asked in the comment) then you can affix a little bit of jQuery to dynamically set the `margin-top` of your `.content` section.

Here is a fiddle showing you how: https://jsfiddle.net/n4ebgmo7/3/

Here is the needed jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').css({
    'margin-top':$('.jumbotron').outerHeight()
  });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the jumbotron doesn't have a fixed height. This is for a wordpress theme, that means that the user can change how much text is in the jumbotron and it will also change height.

Comment: You would have to use jQuery/Javascript to dynamically set the margin-top. I have edited my answer to include this resolve for you as well, if you want to see it in action, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n4ebgmo7/2/  :)

Comment: Why is width: 100% making extra margin-right on content?

Comment: When you set an element's position to `fixed`, it generates its width based on the content inside it, unless otherwise specified. The fiddle seems to be fine without it, but more often than not, it can cause problems on the live site. If your live website works fine without it, then I wouldn't worry about keeping it, feel free to take it out - it's just a precaution :)

Comment: If you do need to stick to the `width:100%` rule, remember to add `* {box-sizing:border-box;}` to your CSS to fix the "extra margin" on the right - see fixed fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/n4ebgmo7/3/

Comment: I am new to web development, I don't think this should cause problems on mobile or IE, am I right?

Comment: No. For future reference, you can compare CSS rules and their support at caniuse.com. :) If you have more questions about this, we can move this discussion to chat (so that we don't clog up the comment section), or alternatively formulate a full question and post it :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.jumbotron {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/1920/1080");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    padding: 40px 10px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
  <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
  <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
</section>
```